# App running in iFrame rendering to parent DOM via React Portal

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend

So I have a application architecture somewhat like this. 
There is parent app is a shell that handles loading plugins, service communication, as well a owning an app bar. It can load "content plugins" that are served of a different server (currently these are react apps being rendered in an iframe). Parent child communication happens over postMessage

I would like to expose a container within the parent app bar, where the child could render its navigation model. This is difficult since the child runs in its own iframe.

Is what im trying to achieve possible? If not is there a way I could rearchitect this to support my use case without using iframes

Answer (score 0):

what i was looking for was the

[window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent) property. Also this only works for same origin frames.